# adding spaces in between strings in php

Tags: php, string, email, sendmail

this is the code below, want I wanted to do is add a space in between `.$pass` string and `.$username` string but keeps throwing me errors when I try to accomplish it. any suggestions on how to do this?

```
send_mail('az_barter@noreply.com',
   $_POST['email'],
  'Registration System Demo - Your New Password',
  'Your password is: '.$pass .$username);
```

it always seems to show both the username and password together instead of being seperated thanks in advance for advice.

```
function send_mail($from,$to,$subject,$body)
{
    $headers = '';
    $headers .= "From: $from\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-to: $from\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $from\n";
    $headers .= "Message-ID: <" . md5(uniqid(time())) . "@" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ">\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Date: " . date('r', time()) . "\n";

    mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
}
```

I have updated the post to show the email headers, yes i know md5 booo right it'll be fixed in debugging mode at the moment anyway test purposes only.

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, but you have no `$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";` in the headers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate a whitespace character to your string between those two variables:

```
send_mail('az_barter@noreply.com',
    $_POST['email'],
    'Registration System Demo - Your New Password',
    'Your password is: '.$pass . ' ' . $username);
                               ^^^^^^^
                                HERE
```

Comment: yeah tried that did not work. I'll google the hell out of it I guess and check it out I will post it here when I find the solution. thanks though for the responce :D

Comment: although just to recap on what i said i believe it's in the headers somewhere that i'm missing.